# Javascript alert if JSON response has designated row

Tags: javascript, json, alert

I'm trying to build an app that gets JSON from server and then shows a javascript alert if the JSON response has designated row. The JSON I get from server looks like this:

```
{
    "key": [
        {
            "IND": "406",
            "NUMBER": "9",
            "MESSAGE": "this is a test",
            "status": "ok"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the code I use to show the alert:

```
function UpdateRecord(update_id) {
    var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL + "test.php",
        data: 'id=' + id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'ok') {
                alert(data.message);
            } else {
                alert("no");
            }
        }
    });
}​
```

But this code alerts "no" even though the JSON has a row  `"status": "ok"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have "key" defined in your jSON, sohould it not be

```
if(data.key[0].status == "ok")
```

Comment: is the above json exactly what is being returned? console.log(<string>) is the best way to debug javascript as it will print to the browser console, you should print out at various points to make sure you are getting the correct response / variables. with JSON imagine the variable name being a link to the first curly brace, you then have to step through each level to get what you want. data= {key.....}, data.key= [{status...}], data.key[0] = {status....}  etc etc

Comment: yes, that is exactly the same response as I get from the server. I used `console.log(data)`and pasted that to JSON validator and it is a valid JSON.

Comment: I just copied the JSON above into a var on google chrome console and ran data.key[0].status; it returned "ok". something else is going on, an above answer suggested adding dataType JSON to the request, try that, else it could be a typo or something like that as its working for me, try it urself if you have chrome (its console is great for testing a few lines)

Comment: I had to add a `header('Content-Type: application/json');`to the PHP file before i json_encoded it. Now it works fine, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try with `if (data.key[0].status)`, and replace `alert(data.message)` with `alert(data.key[0].MESSAGE)`. You have to be careful with capitalization!

Comment: @ user: If you look at your quoted JSON, think of `data` as pointing to *the whole thing*. Hence Cyrille's point that the `status` property you're looking for is at `data.key[0].status`. And all JavaScript property names are case-sensitive, so `message` won't match `MESSAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `console.log(data)` in the success handler to see what the data is. You will see that there is no `data.status`, but instead it would be `data.key[0].status`.